# How do I automatically (after boot) mount an USB disk for the general user read/write/execute

Tags: boot, usb, mount, usb-storage, debian-wheezy

This question has been answered several times here, however I want the disks been mounted **automatically** *after boot* - with an entry in /etc/fstab

presently I have:
/dev/sdc1       /media/disk500  vfat   user,umask=0000   0   0
in my **fstab**
however this does not do it automatically after boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- maybe you want to add rw,auto in the options field.
   rw : to enable
  any i/o on the disk.
   auto : to mount it at boot time.
   i suggest you
  try it. 
  you are assuming it will be in sdc, that implies that sda
  (normally the primary disk that contains the OS) and sdb(another
  storage device, another disk mayebe ?), let's say you removed the
  disk on sdb, then your usb device will be at sdb and sdc will be
  empty that's why i suggest you mount it by uuid.
   run this command to
  find the uuid :

  ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/

  now you must see list of symbolic links, find the file that points to your usb device and the name of that file should be your uiid.

  now type this in fstab:

  UUID=uuid_of_the_usb_device /media/disk500 vfat auto,rw,user 0 0

---

Comment: This answer would be much improved if you were to [edit] it to describe how to do that, and what the effect of doing it will be.

Comment: This was it: so I - in the meantime - entered into /etc/fstab:
/dev/sdc1       /media/disk500  vfat   user,umask=0000   0   0
of course assuming that during boot **sdc** will come as the usb-disk .... strangely enough I also got **sdd** but never could reproduce it ... :)

I hope this will be kept now forever!

As a matter of fact: this strange behaviour occurred **after** installing a new software package (octave) and there about 500 or more packages were modified ... I used **synaptic**

Comment: @jorgepeine glad i could help

Comment: just a small remark: I recently discovered that when I plug in two USB-Drives --- the /dev/sdc device gets lost! interesting ... so I firstly plugin only one disk, wait until system is up then plug-in the next one ...